# Go to item in array

Tags: c

I am looking at an example of `calloc`, and it says it creates pointer pointing to first element. So I was thinking, how could I pull an item out such as, if I had an array, `car[5] = 1,2,3,4,5`, I would then go to `car[1]` to pull a specific element out.

I can't do `*parr[2]` so I am thinking `(*parr+2)` would work however I'm not sure if its the correct way to do this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#define NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS 100


int main(){
    int32_t *parr = calloc(NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS, sizeof(int32_t));
    if (parr == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Couldn't allocate memory");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Memory allocation succesful");
        printf("Item at start is,%d",(*parr+2));
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `parr[1]`? Not clear what your actual issue is unless it is just knowing that any pointer can be dereferenced with array syntax. `Item at start` but why would the start be at `+2`? Really not clear what you are intending.

Comment: `parr[2]` or `*(parr + 2)`. Most people prefer the former syntax.

Comment: Also note that there is no need to print out any of the elements at that point. `calloc` zeroes everything so you know for sure what the value is already. Perhaps you are just using that as an example but just pointing it out in case not.

Comment: I was just using it as an example thanks for the insight

Comment: The format specifier should be `"%"PRId32`,  or cast argument to match format specifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have allocated a simple one-dimensional array `parr`, use the array notation `parr[2]` to read or set the value at element 2. It's the same simple rules as array literal (same as `car[5]` in the question)

`*(parr + 2)` is also valid.

`(*parr + 2)` is `(parr[0] + 2)`, it evaluates to `0 + 2 = 2`

`(*parr + 2) = 3;` is invalid, because it can't assign `3` to `2`.

`*parr[2]` is invalid, it can't be de-referenced.

It gets more complicated if the address of the array is passed to a function, or for multi-dimensional arrays.